# Is every even integer $\geq 6$ the sum of two totients?

Tags: number-theory

1) Is it true for every even integer $n \geq 6$ that there exist integers $x, y$ such that
$$n = \varphi(x) + \varphi(y)?$$
For example:
$6 = 2+4 = \varphi(3) + \varphi(5),$
$8 = 4+4 = \varphi(5) + \varphi(5),$
$10 = 4+6 = \varphi(5) + \varphi(7),$
and so forth.

2) Since I have known (please see comments below) that question 1) is an open problem, I narrow down the ranges of $x$ and $y$:

Is it true for every even integer $n \geq 6$ that there exist composite integers $x, y$ such that
$$n = \varphi(x) + \varphi(y)?$$

Comment: If the Goldbach Conjecture is true, then this follows.

Comment: @user137794: Hi thanks. But how did you see that?

Comment: Assuming Goldbach, any even number $n+2\geq8$ is a sum of two primes. $n+2=p+q, n=\varphi(p)+\varphi(q)$

Comment: Ah, right. By definition of the totients of primes.

Comment: So is anyone for that I am going to delete this question?

Comment: According to Mathworld, this is still open: see equation 33 at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html .  Also, naturally, it's originally due to Erdős.

Comment: I'd like to add again that if $n=\varphi(p)+\varphi(q)$ then for 2), we have $n=\varphi(2p)+\varphi(2q)$.